# Eliminate variable in Maple

Tags: maple

I tried to search, and found some answers that were sort of relevant. However I could not get it to work.

So, I have two equations $x=f(\xi)$ and $z = g(\xi)$, both being affine, thus invertible.

More precisely the equations are
$$
x=\frac{1+\varepsilon}{4(2+\varepsilon)}\left(\xi - 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)t^2 + \frac{1}{2+\varepsilon}\xi (t+1)
$$
and
$$
z=\frac{1+\varepsilon}{2(2+\varepsilon)}\left(\xi - 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)t + \frac{1}{2+\varepsilon}\xi.
$$

Maple:

`x = (1+varepsilon)*(xi-1-(1/2)*varepsilon)*t^2/(4*(2+varepsilon))+xi*(t+1)/(2+varepsilon)`

`z = (1+varepsilon)*(xi-1-(1/2)*varepsilon)*t/(2*(2+varepsilon))+xi/(2+varepsilon)`.

I would like to eliminate $\xi$ and write $z = h(x)$, where $h$ should be as simplified as possible. This should be possible to do in Maple.

Comment: Do you mean $z=h(x,t)$?

Comment: please,write  $x$ and $z$ in  Maple format,not in Latex

Comment: @Leox: is it admissible now?

Comment: @quasi: it may be a slight abuse of notation.

Comment: You're missing a * for multiplication in the first equation. You have xi(t+1). Presumably you intended xi*(t+1). Maple interprets xi(t+1) as function evaluation (where xi is an unknown function), not multiplication.

Comment: Thank you, that was it!

Comment: @Anonymous -- what are you talking about?

Comment: He did not at all steal your method. It is only really one way to eliminate a variable, from a system of equations, and this question asked specifically about using Maple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using straightforward elimination of variables . . .
[image]

Here's the code in text format . . .

`restart;
eq1:=x=(1+e)/(4*(2+e))*(w-1-e/2)*t^2+(1/(2+e))*(w*(t+1));
eq2:=z=(1+e)/(2*(2+e))*(w-1-e/2)*t+(1/(2+e))*w;
solve(eq1,w);
subs(w=%,eq2);
factor(%);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you sure you've read the equations correctly?
 $\varepsilon$  is just a constant, and not the same as $\xi$. It seems that you have used $e$ for both. Other than that, could you explain what you are doing?

Comment: No, I didn't see that. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Fixed now, I think: Note: I'm using $w$ instead of $\xi$, and $e$ instead of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, that's something along the lines of what I'm trying to do. Could you paste the code as text? I've tried to write it down, but solve throws an error. And what does % mean?

Comment: % is the previous result

Comment: Your approach seems to be the best solution, however solve still complains, even though I'm pasting your code line by line. I was under the delusion that Maple could make my life a little easier, but every time I try do do even the simplest thing it's an absolute nightmare.

Comment: Can you paste an image of your maple session?

Comment: I'm using the classic window version  of maple.

Comment: The command-line version should also work.

Comment: Maple is worth learning -- it really _will_ make your life easier, once you learn how to work around the places where Maple doesn't automatically do what you want.

Comment: The site is encouraging me to move this discussion to chat, but I am not allowed. Are you able to do it? I really need to get to bed now, so cannot try anything until tomorrow. I did accept your answer though. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll be busy this time tomorrow.

Comment: Did you see my comment about the missing * symbol?

Comment: My pasted text is missing some * symbols also. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Try it now. Just make sure all multiplications are _explicit_ (i.e., using the * symbol). Maple doesn't have implied multiplication.

Comment: Now it works like charm!

Comment: @quasi Please join us here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107315/maple

Answer (score 1):

There is a Maple command for this kind of thing, called `eliminate`.

[edited: I did not initially understand which variables were to be eliminated. So below it now eliminates both `z` and `w`.]

I'll follow quasi's Answer by using `w` for `xi`, etc.

Using `eliminate` here does not require coming up (on your own) with a set of solving steps (such as solving cleverly for `w`, subsituting, etc).

```
restart;
eq1:=x=(1+e)/(4*(2+e))*(w-1-e/2)*t^2+(1/(2+e))*(w*(t+1)):
eq2:=z=(1+e)/(2*(2+e))*(w-1-e/2)*t+(1/(2+e))*w:

raw:=eliminate({eq1,eq2},{z,w}):

sol:=eval(z,raw[1]);

                2                      2                    
             e t  - 4 e t x + 2 e t + t  - 4 t x + 2 t - 8 x
    sol := - -----------------------------------------------
                           /   2    2          \            
                         2 \e t  + t  + 4 t + 4/
```

That result can be simplified, though you have not been precise about what you mean by it being as simplified as "possible".

```
z=simplify(sol,size);

                     2                                  
           (-e - 1) t  + ((4 x - 2) e + 4 x - 2) t + 8 x
       z = ---------------------------------------------
                                     2                  
                      8 + (2 e + 2) t  + 8 t            

z=collect(numer(sol),e,factor)
  /collect(denom(sol),e,factor);

           -t (t - 4 x + 2) e - (t + 2) (t - 4 x)
       z = --------------------------------------
                         2            2          
                    2 e t  + 2 (t + 2)
```

The result from the `eliminate` command also returns restrictions remaining (implied) on the other variables (parameters). In the code above that would be `raw[2]`, and for this example that is the empty set, which means that `solve({eq1,eq1},{z,w})` would produce the same answer since the remaining variables are free.

Answer (score 0):

I can might as well post the code I ended up using, which add constraints to the variables and stays true to the notation in the first post.

`assume(varepsilon > 0, t > 0, xi, 'real', x, 'real', z, 'real');
eqn1 := x = (1+varepsilon)*(xi-1-(1/2)*varepsilon)*t^2/(4*(2+varepsilon))+xi*(t+1)/(2+varepsilon);
eqn2 := z = (1+varepsilon)*(xi-1-(1/2)*varepsilon)*t/(2*(2+varepsilon))+xi/(2+varepsilon);
solve(eqn1, xi);
subs(xi = %, eqn2);
factor(%);`

Comment: Please join us here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107315/maple